# Prove that $\chi(G) \ge n/(n - d)$, being $\chi(G)$ the chromatic number of $G$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on the following graph theory excercise:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices, which is regular of degree $d$. By considering the number of vertices that can be assigned the same colour, prove that $\chi(G) ≥ n/(n - d)$, being $\chi(G)$ the chromatic number of $G$

I'm starting from the theorem that says: For every graph $G$:

$$\chi(G) ≤ 1 + \Delta(G)$$

As $\Delta(G) = d$, then

$$\chi(G) ≤ 1 + d$$

and $n/n = 1$ then

$$\chi(G) ≤ n/n + d$$

What am I missing to fit my procedure into the way requested? Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: Have you tried using the hint about "considering the number of vertices that can be assigned the same colour"? How many vertices can be assigned the same colour?

Comment: If $G$ is a graph on $n$ vertices, and $G$ is coloured with $\chi(G)$ colours, with no colour being used more than $t$ times, can you prove that $n\le t\cdot\chi(G)$? Can you prove that $\chi(G)\ge n/t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\chi (G) < \frac {n}{n-d} \iff n-d<\frac { n}{\chi (G) }$ . Then we have one color $k$ such that at least $n-d+1$ vertices have that color. Then all these vertices are non adjacent. So degree of any one such vertex $\leq d-1$ which is a contradiction.